# Why can image search engines use all images without asking for permission?

Tags: licensing

I have an image on my website, which I created myself.
I have not added any license. The photo is just there.

Google is showing the image in their image search.
They also modified it by creating a thumbnail in reduced quality.
The thumbnail seems to be stored on their servers.

When you click on the image, Google shows the hint
"Images may be subject to copyright."

I know it's possible to write a robots.txt file to forbid Google to show my image. It's also possible to write them a message.

But why is Google allowed to use images without asking for permission?
I always thought you need a license or permission to redistribute and modify an image of someone else.

I am registered to the Google Search Console. Maybe I granted them the right to use my image there, but I don't know.
I cannot find the image on bing, yahoo or duckduckgo.

Comment: Good question, I have the same one.